# Using knitr to create HTML slide with separate output of just the R code

Tags: r, markdown, knitr

I am using `knitr` to create a set of lecture slides for a class using R.  I would like to create a separate "companion file" that contains just has the R code (corresponding to the slides), so that students can execute the R code by cutting and pasting from the companion file.

For example, in the .Rmd file:

````
``` {r ....}
plot(x,y)
```
````

Then there would be a text file with:

```
plot(x,y)
```

But, have such a file be automatically produced from the .Rmd file?

Even better if the .Rmd file has such tags:

````
``` {r basic.plot ....}
plot(x,y)
```
````

Then, text file has:

```
# basic.plot
plot(x,y)
```

Can this be accomplished using knitr?

Comment: Yes. Add `tangle = TRUE` when you are running `knit` and all code chunks will automatically be saved in an R file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. What you're trying to do is called *tangling*, and it comes from the world of [literate programming](http://www.literateprogramming.com/).

The `knit` function [supports a `tangle` option](http://www.rforge.net/doc/packages/knitr/knit.html) that should be set to `TRUE` if you want to extract source code.

Comment: or just `purl()`, for short.

Comment: Thank you everyone.  The tangle=TRUE option produced the desired output.  Thank you both for provided the solution and the background explanation.